# PHP GLOB skips the first image in each folder

Tags: php, glob

I am trying to understand why GLOB is skipping the first image in whatever folder I direct it too. I work around it by placing a dummy image named so it is listed first but I would like to solve this irk in a more efficient way. Here is my code.

```
   <?php

    // This retrieves images from a selected folder - anchor with a data-xx-xx    attribute
    // via jQuery - click - the data-xx-x value is put into a hidden field :   foldpath

    // It all works fine BUT, it always fails to return the first image in a folder
    // I get around it by placing within each folder a dummy image called aa.jpg 
    // which hopefully will always be the first image but it is not really a 
    // satisfactory solution.

if($_POST && isset($_POST["foldsub"]) && isset($_POST["foldpath"]) ){
    // hidden field $_POST["foldpath"];
    //A typical path might be :

    // ../images/products/CLIENTS_images/bridal_whatnots/bridal_belts
    //the ../ prefix is reoved via php when the page is displayed and replaced by DIR
    // for testing between admin folders and the main root folders I use the relative paths.

    $fp = $_POST["foldpath"]; 
    $files = glob($fp ."/" ."*.*");
    //this is a pop up page which needs to stay open after the selection has been made
    echo "<script> $(\"#imgstuff\").css({\"display\":\"block\"});</script>";
    //the form closed on whgen the close x is selected
    }else
    {
        //default
   $files = glob("../images/bannerImgs/*.*");      
    }    

  for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)    
{

$image = $files[$i];

$supported_file = array(
      'jpg',
      'jpeg',
      'png'
);

$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
   // print $image ."<br />";
$path = $image;
$path1 = DIR;
if (strpos($path, $path1) !== false) {
    $path2 = $path;
}else{
$path2 = str_replace('../', '', $path);
$path2 = $path1.$path2;
}

$fn = basename($path);

$fn = basename($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if($fn!="aa.jpg"){
 echo '<p class="imgdet">';
// echo '<span class="imglongpath">' . $path2 .'</span>';
    echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" />';
    echo '<span class="imgname">' . $fn .'</span>';
  // echo '<span class="imgmesg">Now click Confirm / Set Choice</span>';
   // "<br /><br />";
echo "</p>";
}
} else {
    continue;
 }    
}    
?>
```

Comment: could you please provide a list of the files in your folder, a `var_dump($files)` and an example output of your code? (on a side note - feeding unsanitized user-data ($_POST["foldpath"]) directly into a filesystem-function is a potential security risk.)

Comment: The value is from is_dir search and converted to a string and written into a data-attribute and is served up as a 'button' and jQuery puts the valu into the hidden box.. The user doesn't visually see it unless they go to page source . The output . Let me just understand - you need a list of what is within a folder?

Comment: yes. a list of what is within a folder. that is what i meant with "list of files in your folder".

Comment: Try this:  array(5) { [0]=> string(86) "../images/products/je_images/bridal_accessories/ring_cushions/102FN_(JEC001detail).jpg" [1]=> string(84) "../images/products/je_images/bridal_accessories/ring_cushions/102FN_(JEC001full).jpg" [2]=> string(86) "../images/products/je_images/bridal_accessories/ring_cushions/103FN_(JEC002detail).jpg" [3]=> string(84) "../images/products/je_images/bridal_accessories/ring_cushions/103FN_(JEC002full).jpg" [4]=> string(68) "../images/products/je_images/bridal_accessories/ring_cushions/aa.jpg" }

Comment: from this list the one which would not show is [4] aa.jpg, which visually is the first in the folder

Comment: I have to say something which is embarrassing - for some unknown reason, this is now working OK. Why suddenly is should I have no idea. Fortunately this is development rather than live so hopefully it is a dev environment issue. Thank you for looking anyway. Should the problem return I'll repost with salient details. Thank you for looking.

Comment: It is the famous "My code works, i dont know why. My Code does not work, i dont know why" meme :P

Comment: @PuyaSarmidani well, if it doesn't work and you don't know why, that's better than if it does work and you don't know why.